# How do you create/initialize Javassist ClassPool inside a OSGi Bundle?

Tags: classpath, osgi

I created a Bundle in Eclipse, and used the "Launch the Framework" link for the "Overview" tab. I have created an interface (TestService) in my bundle, and code that should generate a proxy for it (in Helper). I call this code in the Activator of the Bundle, and get:

```
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: com.test.services.TestService
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:436)
at com.test.services.Helper.get(Helper.java:46)
```

It throws right at the first ClassPool.get():

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass result = pool.get(TestService.class.getName());
...
```

TestService is public and in the same package, and Bundle, as the Helper, which generates the Exception. Obviously, it's not good enough to just do "ClassPool.getDefault()". So what do I need to do so that ClassPool sees the classes inside the Bundle? Do I have to import my own packages?

Comment: I assume that the javassist bundle itself would need visibility of the classes you are asking it to load. Unfortunately I don't know how javassist looks up classes. Can you tell it which classloader to use, or does it just take a random guess? Can it be configured with actual `Class` objects, or does it insist on classnames supplied as Strings?

Comment: I'm just beginning with Javassist, so I'm not sure, but I'll check this evening and answer you. But, I suspect you pointed out that problem already; OSGi limit the packages that a Bundle can see, so it might be enough to add my own package in the "import package" of the Javassist Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use javassist in some OSGi bundles to modify/generate Java classes on the fly. You can just look [here](https://github.com/knowhowlab/org.knowhowlab.osgi.shell/tree/master/equinox/src/main/java/org/knowhowlab/osgi/shell/equinox). Hope it helps you.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with Javassit in it's own Bundle, because I get a circular dependency, but I just don't get how to embed the Javassit jar in the Bundle with my code. I'll just have to "assume" that it works, until I find useable instructions on how to do the embedding manually (not using Maven).

Comment: Which tool do you use to build your OSGi bundle? Ant? You can use http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd tool directly to embed jar and create the bundle.

Comment: I'm using Bnd, but just started. I'm reading "OSGi in Practice", and the author uses Bnd. But I just finished chapter two so I haven't read about embedding. Anyway, I think this is the wrong approach for me. Since I know exactly what I should "generate" at compile time, it would make more sense for me to use Javassist at compile time instead. That would make one less runtime dependency, while solving the classpath problem at the same time..

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: the link is fixed

Answer (score 10):

If "source" is an object loaded by an OSGi bundle classloader, you can the corresponding "classpath" (or classloader) to the ClassPool, like this:

```
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(source.getClass()));
```

or in your case simply

```
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(TestService.class));
```

Hope it helps.